# Bundler install doesn't work with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, bundler, rbenv

I'm trying to get a Middleman static site going but for the life of me cannot get Bundler to act right. This is my first time using Ruby on Rails.

Using rbenv I’ve cloned ruby 2.2.0 into a plugin folder but even after running rbenv global 2.2.0 and getting Middleman and Bundler to install, I can't get the "bundle install" or any other "bundle --" commands to work.

I was having issues with permissions and different versions of Ruby even after rbenv so I added "export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" to my bash profile.

Once that was done the Ruby version issue that was keeping me from installing Bundler and Middleman was gone. But now that they're installed, I can't get these gems to follow any commands.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how they're not working? Copy and paste the exact error that you're getting into your question. Please also paste the output from `gem env`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ruby -v` to see what local ruby version is set in the app.

`rbenv versions` to see if you have that version installed. If you don't have the right version installed, run `rbenv install ruby-x.x.x` or whatever version is required, or if it is already installed do `rbenv local x.x.x`.

After installing a new ruby you need to run `rbenv rehash` to rehash your shims.

Then probably `gem install bundler`, then you can try `bundle install`.